# In what situations should I use Wh words?

Tags: questions

My question, How do I use the WH words correctly?

Does some rule exist for their use?

Do I only use them to ask questions? Or how can I use them in affirmative sentences?

For example:

"What" and "That" have the same meaning, but they are used in a different way.

- Which is the best school?
- I liked the pie that she did.

How not to confuse the use of those words?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you think is/isn't correct?

Comment: Wh-words function as relative pronouns in affirmative sentences like: "I love the man *who* painted this" and "I like *where* you live."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Wh* words are also called the *Journalist's Questions* in many style guides as well as introductory Journalism. Basically, whenever a Journalist is assigned a task of reporting an event (such as a presidential campaign or release of a product) that he/she has no knowledge of, the first starting point of investigation (or brainstorming) to create a story are the Journalist's Questions.

For example, in case of a presidential campaign:

- **Who** are the candidates? What's their background?
- **What** are they all campaigning about?
- **When** is the campaign going to start?
- **Where** exactly (states or counties) is the campaign going to take place?
- **How** (what process, expenses, business contacts, etc.) is the campaign going to happen?

So, to answer your question, the *Wh* questions are to be used when you want to investigate or brainstorm about an unknown topic.